# Struggling with a SPARQL query over DBpedia

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, dbpedia

**My goal:** Have a list of the Smartphones from DBpedia associated with manufacturers. 
**Example:** 
Iphone 6 | Apple
Samsung Galaxy S6 | Samsung
Iphone 5 | Apple
Sony xperia Z5 | Sony
**What I did:**
I think that it would be a union query. So as a first step I tried to get all the smartphone list and I succeeded using this query:

```
SELECT ?phone 
where {?phone <http://dbpedia.org/property/type> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Smartphone>}
```

However I didn't succeed to get the manufactures list. I tried this query in order to get the manufacturer of the Iphone 6. But it didn't work.

```
SELECT ?Manufacturer 
where {?Manufacturer <http://dbpedia.org/property/manufacturer> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Smartphone>}
```

Comment: This should have been an edit to one of your earlier questions under your other account, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171909/a-simlpe-sparql-query-over-dbpedia-and-using-python .

Comment: Right, I was thinking the same when I saw this here, but somehow my comment got lost. @Amir Ladhar: Can you give us the reason for creating a new account and post a - to some extend related question to your previous one? And wouldn't it make sense to reply to peoples comments and/or questions?

Comment: BY the way, what you "tried" is something that I showed to you, so it would be nice to refer to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
?phone dbp:type dbr:Smartphone
```

This triple roughly means: "the `type` of `?phone` is `Smartphone`". That makes sense, so you get what you want.

```
?manufacturer dbp:manufacturer dbr:Smartphone
```

This triple means: "the `manufacturer` of `?manufacturer` is `Smartphone`". That doesn't make any sense, `Smartphone` is not something that can be a manufacturer. This is why you get no results.

What you want is:

- the `type` of `?phone` is `Smartphone`
- the `manufacturer` of `?phone` is `?manufacturer`

In SPARQL:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?phone dbp:type dbr:Smartphone.
  ?phone dbp:manufacturer ?manufacturer.
}
```

Comment: Thank that's perfect